# importing a specific symbol from module in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I would like to know if there's any way to import only specific symbol in LLVM.
Take a look at this javascript example in node:

```js
import mySymbol from 'some/path.mylang'
```

I've already seen this post on stackoverflow: [LLVM ir how to import other modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911045/llvm-ir-how-to-import-other-modules)
but it really isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

If LLVM doesn't allow to import only specific symbols from a module, then how can I implement this? Maybe string manipulation and regex on generated .ll files and concatenating them?

Answer (score 0):

Use `llvm-extract` to produce a module that contains only the symbol you want, then llvm-link against that?

Normally an LLVM module must have a list of all symbols it's going to import anyways, but in this case "import" means "that this modules uses but are defined by some other Module". That doesn't seem to be what you mean by import?

If you mean that you want to clone a function into your module using the C++ API just call CloneFunction on that one function you want to copy into your other module?